# Google Photos--disable grouping photos by day

Tags: gallery, google-photos, android-10

The Google Photos App for Android groups photos by day. However, this feature becomes a problem when taking photos only occasionally. Only one photo per row is displayed, most of the time *(see screenshot)*.

Zooming out makes the app group by month, however the pictures appear much smaller then.

**Question:** Is There a way to disable grouping and just display the same amout of pictures per row?

There are lots of alternative gallery apps. However, only Google Photos can be used to view the gallery without downloading the images, as far as I'm aware.

[image: Google Photos Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Only synchronization options are available to us, users. As additional options you can enable grouping photos by faces and adding photos/videos from Google Disk to the gallery. No "turn off the date grouping notion" available. The only way to change the order is to edit the photo itself - this way, the files would be organized according to edit date